# Best case height for a binary tree with N internal nodes

Tags: algorithm, tree, binary-tree

I am working through Algorithms in C++ by Robert Sedgewick and came across the following statement:

> The height of a binary tree with `N` internal nodes is at least `lg N`
>   and at most `N-1`. The best case occurs in a balanced tree with `2^i`
>   internal nodes at every level except possibly the bottom level. If the
>   height is "h" then we must have
>
> ```
>          2^(h-1) < N+1 <= 2^h
> ```
>
> since there are N+1 external nodes.

There wasn't much explanation surrounding the inequality, so my question is: how did the author deduce the inequality and what is it showing exactly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inequality `2^(h-1) < N + 1 <= 2^h` demonstrates that, for a given height `h`, there is a range of node quantities that will have `h` as a minimum height in common. This is indicative of the property: all binary trees containing *N* nodes will have a height of at least log(*N*) rounded up to the next integer.

For example, a tree with either `4, 5, 6 or 7` nodes can have at best a minimum height of `3`. One less than this range, and you can have a tree of height `2`; one more and the best you can do is a height of `4`.
If we map out the minimum height for a tree that grows from `3` nodes to `8` nodes using the base 2 logarithms for *N* and round up, the inequality becomes clear:

```
log(3) = 1.58 -> 2  [lower bound]

log(4) = 2    -> 3  [2^(h-1)]
log(5) = 2.32 -> 3
log(6) = 2.58 -> 3
log(7) = 2.81 -> 3

log(8) = 3    -> 4  [2^h | upper bound]
```

It might be useful to notice that the range (made up of `N+1` different quantities) is directly related to the number of external nodes for a given tree. Take a tree with `3` nodes and having a height of `2`:

```
     *
    / \
   *   *
```

add one node to this tree,

```
    *          *          *          *
   / \        / \        / \        / \
  *   *  or  *   *  or  *   *  or  *   *
 /            \            /            \
*              *          *              *
```

and regardless of where you place it, the height will increase by 1. We can then keep creating leaf nodes without changing the height until the tree contains 7 nodes in total, at which point, any further additions will increase the minimum possible height once more:

```
    *
   / \
  *   *
 / \ / \
*  * *  *
```

Originally, *N* was equal to `3` nodes, which meant `N+1 = 4` and we saw that there were `4` quantities that had a common minimum height.

If you need more information, I suggest you look up the properties of complete and balanced binary trees.

Answer (score 0):

Let's call the minimum height required to fit `N` nodes in a binary tree `minheight(N)`.

One way to derive a lower bound on the tree height for a given number `N` of nodes is to work from the other direction: given a tree of height `h`, what is the maximum number of nodes that can be packed into it?

Let's call this function of height `maxnodes(h)`.  Clearly the number of nodes on a binary tree of given height is maximised when the tree is *full*, i.e. when each internal node has 2 children.  Induction will quickly show that `maxnodes(h) = 2^h - 1`.

So, if we have `N` nodes, every `h` for which `maxnodes(h) >= N` is *an* upper bound for `minheight(N)`: that is, you could fit all `N` nodes on a tree of that height.  Of all these upper bounds, the best (tightest) one will be the minimum.  So what we want to find is the smallest `h` such that

```
N <= maxnodes(h) = 2^h - 1
```

So how to find this smallest satisfying value of `h`?

The important property of `maxnodes(h)` is that it is nondecreasing w.r.t. `h` (in fact it's strictly increasing, but nondecreasing is sufficient).  What that means is that you can never fit more nodes into a full binary tree by reducing its height.  (Obvious really but it helps to spell things out sometimes!)  This makes rearranging the above equation to find the minimum value of `h` easy:

```
2^h - 1 >= N
2^h >= N+1        # This is the RHS of your inequality, just flipped around
h >= log2(N+1)    # This step is only allowed because log(x) is nondecreasing
```

`h` must be integer, so the smallest value of `h` satisfying `h >= log2(N+1)` is `RoundUp(log2(N+1))`.

I find this to be the most useful way to describe the lower bound, but it can be used to derive the LHS of the inequality you're asking about.  Starting from the 2nd equation in the previous block:

```
2^h >= N+1
```

The set of `h` values that satisfy this inequality begins at `h = log2(N+1)` and stretches out to positive infinity.  Since `h = log2(N+1)` is the minimum satisfying value in this set, anything lower must not satisfy the inequality, so in particular `h-1` will not satisfy it.  If a `>=` inequality does not hold between two real (non-infinite) numbers then the corresponding `<` inequality must hold, so:

```
2^(h-1) < N+1
```